# Get actual Environment status through TFS api

Tags: testing, tfs, lab-management

We use Visual Studio LabManagement infrustructure and TFS API to run our automation test from builds. Some of our test require reboot of system before they can be launched.
We noticed strange behaviour. When QtAgent is stoped by system (and not with a button Stop, pressed by human being),  Test Controller is not notified automatically and environment remains in Ready state (status). 
It goes to error when we invoke WaitForEnvironmentReady activity to determine that test machine is really ready to execute test (or other word connection between QtAgent service and Test Controller has been already established).

Is there a way to force Test Controller to get actual information about state of Environment  without waiting for timeout is expired.

Answer (score 0):

The controller will come to know about the agent going down after a timeout period specified in the testcontroller configuration xml. Once the controller detects this the environment state should move to notready on next refresh.

You can change these defaults as needed
See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934570.aspx